# javascript: replace linebreak

Tags: javascript, replace, line-breaks

I'm having a string which contains a chr(13) as linebreak. How can i replace it with eg. `<br>`? I tried `mystring.replace("\n","<br>");` but it didn't work

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784313/read-line-break-in-a-string-with-javascript

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to assign the line break to a variable?

Answer (score 31):

`"\n"` is chr(10). I think you want `"\r"`:

```
mystring.replace("\r", "<br>");
```

---

Updated: To replace ALL \r use a regular expression:

```
mystring.replace(/\r/g, "<br>");
```

---

If you want it to work with Windows, Unix and Mac style line breaks use this:

```
mystring.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, "<br>");
```

Comment: Yep, chr(13) is '\r', not '\n'.

Comment: good news - it worked. but unfortunately only for the first linebreak (there's several in my string). any ideas?

Comment: you need to use the g flag in a regexp like in my answer, and not only take into account \r but \n too

Comment: Of course if you know the character code, you can always just use mystring.replace(String.fromCharCode(13), "<br>");

Comment: I like the third one above, nice solution. Is it not standard though to use <br /> instead of <br>? I could be wrong.

Answer (score 8):

```
theString.replace(/\n|\r/g, '<br />')
```